# In Islam can you wear clothes like crop tops and shorts in front of my siblings and parents?

Tags: halal-haram, women

I want to wear shorts at home but don't know if I could I'm the only girl in my family so what do I do?

Comment: The majority view is that the area from the navel to the knees (at minimum) is 'awrah. Be it for a male or female, or be it infront of mahrams.

Answer (score 0):

The limits of covering and hijab are different in different Islamic religions and in different Islamic cultures and nationalities. And they differ from country to country.
But what all Islamic religions agree on is that it is like a private part from the top of the chest to the knees, and it is obligatory for women to cover this area. Women should cover this area even in front of other women.

But the limits of dress and clothing against incest like father and brother, I must say that these limits are more and more comprehensive. Women should cover from the neck to the ankles. Therefore, wearing a top that exposes women's breasts and tight shorts is haram in front of an incestuous woman because it causes corruption and sin. I would like to draw your attention to cases of male rape of an incestuous woman. Brothers rape the daughter or mother of the house ?? In most of these cases, the raped women did not observe the limits of their clothes and clothing against these men. And this is what has created corruption and sin.

http://ensani.ir/fa/article/61001